# Stream audio to a local network

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, networking

i need to make an app that will stream audio from http url, I have everything done except this thing, i cannot do the streaming from a device, I need to make an url that streams audio to devices from the local network, please help, with some advice, or code samples, or maybe someone has an idea how should i do this, please help !!!

Comment: Do you want to stream to or from the iOS device to the local network?

Comment: A server should be on iOS, and a client iOS should connect to it ...

Answer (score 1):

Implement a local HTTP web server inside your app.  Explained here: [iOS devices as web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804650/ios-devices-as-web-server)

Then serve your audio file.