# hosting a webserver inside iphone and android phones

Tags: php, android, iphone

i am planning to do some servlet for my app to work offline on both android and iphone devices. for this i need to have the stubbed responses on a server.i saw there is one such server for android (http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/). is there is similar server for iPhone ? so that i can develop a single solution to solve both the platforms.

or else you can also get me an alternate idea of using a php kind of server which could work on iPhone and android.

Comment: While I am not a Android/iPhone developer, I don't know for servers. Depenting on the complexity of your application, did you consider to use Sockets or cURL in order to develop your own server with only the tasks required for you application ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS devices as web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804650/ios-devices-as-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think this is possible/practical. Up until recently, iOS prohibits foreign code from being executed on the device, because it poses as a security vulnerability to the device. This would allow you to serve up HTML, Javascript and CSS via your device, but would prohibit most web based programming languages such as PHP from executing on the device.

Recently, Apple recently changed the rules slightly, and allow custom code to be executed on the device, but that code cannot be imported or exported from the application, for security purposes. If you were attempting to build a web server for the iPhone, it would be impractical to write the entire application on your phone!