# iPhone HTTP server works on simulator but not on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, webserver, httpserver

I want to embed a webserver in an iPhone app so as to download files from application's document directory. I am using [iPhone Http Server](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/downloads/detail?name=iPhoneHTTPServer.zip&can=1&q=).

Everything works fine on iPhone simulator. Even I am able to get files using http://: or localhost:.

But on device I am not able to connect. Safari says: "Cannot open page". Even http://iphone.local: doest not work on same device as app is installed.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you open normally other websites?

Comment: Yes. I can. Also is there any setting on iPhone to make it act like webserver. Is there any ports I need to explicitly open for iPhone. Or may be some ports on wifi router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app goes into background, doesn't it?  I think you use Mac's Safari when you try your app in iOS Simulator.   And when you try it on iPhone, your app is in background and iPhone's Safari is foreground.

If so, I believe the following helps you:

cocoaHTTPServer doesn't work in background.
Try keep your app foreground and access it from other machine.

And, there is no way to maintain server functionality all the time...
https://devforums.apple.com/message/706241

Comment: You are right. Now I am able to connect when app is in foreground. But now I have another doubt related to it. I have added code to download files listed. I have added "Content-Disposition = attachment" to make it downlodable. But on device it opens a file in browser itself. How can I make it save on Iphone device

Comment: The proper iOS Safari can't download a file,   or your iPhone has been [jail-broken](http://maketecheasier.com/download-files-directly-into-your-iphone/2010/09/20)?