# Connect iPhone and desktop via HTTP server

Tags: ios, networking

How can I get the IP address of an iPhone and access the internal HTTP server?

I want functionality exactly like the CJournal app, to get the backup files in my desktop computer while both it and the iPhone are on the same network, using a dynamically generated link based on the IP address.

[image]

This is the screenshot from CJournal app , i made a backup for my contacts list through this app then it generated an url which is clearly shown in the image, in the url 192.168.2.7 is IP address of my iphone in my Wi-Fi network. now please suggest me how to generate this url and how to maintain or access the internal http server through my app

Comment: There's no such thing as "internal http server". If you want to run an HTTP server, you need to write one, or add an existing library to your application. You're basically asking how to show the IP address of your iPhone on your app. The HTTP part seems an entire new story.

Comment: Exactly @jweyrich now i am getting my iphone IP address.But dont know how to implement the above functionality present in the image.

Comment: Please, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6804895/298054).

Comment: @jweyrich thank you very much for your support, your link is useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried Zeroconf aka Bonjour? This is a DNS Protokol for Service and Device Discovery which is often used in Apple Environments (eg. Airplay) There is also a Windows Framework provided by Apple. On Linux Devices: take a look into Avahi which seems to be the most complete Solution at the Moment. If you need Help on implementation, take a look at the latest WWDC Videos - there have been several Sessions in the last few years.