# iPhone/iPad as a server

Tags: ios, cocoa, client-server

I want to create an app where clients connect to a server and communicate with each other via images and texts. I already have a server as backend, but is there any way that an iPhone becomes the server? I know that there is `CocoaHTTPServer`, but all of the examples are just a server displaying a webpage. Do you know how I can use it to fit my needs ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to just take all you stuff that now runs on an apache directly to the iPone
You find a couple of tutorials and solutions in the internet.

Maybe this thread can help you: [iOS devices as web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804650/ios-devices-as-web-server)

Concerning CocoaHTTPServer
Maybe have a look at the [SimpleFileUploadServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/tree/master/Samples/SimpleFileUploadServer)