# What is a common way to access a service that is running on an iPad from an iPhone without having internet access?

Tags: ios6

Is there a reference App, or some best practices about how to set up one iOS device as a "server or backend service" like a cashier service and use other iOS devices to access this service/server, like an iPhone as an "electric order notebook"?

Comment: Are you talking about an adhoc connection?  Androids support this quite easily so I'd assume iOS has something similar.  

If you are trying to locate the server without a defined ip-address send a UDP packet to a predefined port on the network broadcast address and have the server return a welcome pack indicating any information that should be known when creating the ip connection

Answer (score 0):

I found out three options:
- Write an own webserver that runs on one device ([iOS devices as web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804650/ios-devices-as-web-server))
- Use Bonjour that allows your server-app to provide services in the network (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/about.html)
- Use GameKit that allows to use the 'Multiplayer' functionality also for non-game Apps (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304)