# Website from with in the app to get app data

Tags: iphone, ios

I have seen some apps like Discover, which is a file management application, has web pages built with in the application. Those pages can be accessed over wifi by entering iphone ip number and port number on any web browser. The page can read and write data into the iphone app.

Whats the process behind this?. What steps do i have to take to create such a web page with in my iphone app.

Comment: use webview like this http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/uiwebview-tutorial.html

Comment: That creates a web browser with in the app. I need to access this from my PC. Say if u hit the url 192.168.1.2:8888, my PC browser will load a web page that can access the files(pictures) in that iphone application.

Comment: @QualityCoder reread the question and pay heed to you nickname :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804650/ios-devices-as-web-server