# Is pure p2p possible on iOS?

Tags: ios, sockets, app-store, p2p

(Knowing Apple's approach to things, I am pretty sure the answer is obvious but I have to ask.)

If you want to provide any examples, just use chat for simplicity.

Obviously, `iOSdevice1-> my server-> Apple Push Notification Server-> iOSdevice2` works, but this is nearly the opposite of p2p.

`iOSDevice1 -> my server-> iOSDevice2` should work, though the long polling necessary may not clear the App Store arbiters. Still not pure p2p.

But what about `iOSDevice1 -> iOSDevice2`? or really... `iOSDevice1 -> one-time ip lookup, iOSDevice1 -> iOSDevice2`

Interested in implementation details, but also so the rules and regulations imposed by Apple for releasing apps with server capabilities.

Comment: Vote to close with no reasoning? Excellent. Very humble indeed.

Comment: Well, you **can** use `NSNetService` (Bonjour), you **can** run a server from within your app, you **can** use the GameKit and CoreBluetooth frameworks for doing it using BT, etc...

Comment: No, but if iOS7 allows real p2p then feel free to share your knowledge

Comment: @H2CO3 - Good ideas. Was unaware that I could run a server from inside the app sandbox. I'll look into that. Would love to hear more from you on NSNetService and a server in the app.

Comment: @user [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [another server](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/)

Comment: Haven't heard of Mongoose before, thanks for that. Some other good iOS HTTP libraries here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804650/ios-devices-as-web-server

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry to hear you're leaving Stack Overflow. You've been a great help.

Comment: @user "No, but if iOS7 allows real p2p then feel free to share your knowledge" No such freedom - breaches NDA.

Comment: @SK9, I don't know that it breaches NDA, it was part of the keynote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see why this scenario - `iOSDevice1 -> one-time ip lookup, iOSDevice1 -> iOSDevice2` wouldn't work, assuming that both devices have publicly routeable IP addresses (or are on the same network).  I think both of them having publicly routeable addresses is pretty unlikely though.

Comment: Yep. That is the extent of my knowledge as well. But I suppose each node could periodically update the lookup table with its current address.

Comment: You can use a dyndns-service like no-ip.org (currently still for free) or build your own service with a simple php-script on your website.

Answer (score 1):

"The Multipeer Connectivity framework (MultipeerConnectivity.framework) supports the discovery of nearby devices and the direct communication with those devices without requiring Internet connectivity."

Go to whats new in iOS7 and you will see this and you can read the docs on it here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328

Comment: Not what I imagined at first, but the information is interesting and appreciated.

Comment: It's not a finalized API so there isn't much information in the documentation and you probably won't find a lot of sample code but the functionality does exist.