# Is possible to communicate via Bluetooth PAN in iOS with tethered devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, network-programming

I have a device with which I share my connection from iOS device though Bluetooth (Bluetooth PAN).

I wonder is it possible to access to create a server on iPhone in PAN network and access it from device or create a server on device and access it from iPhone.

Does anyone have this kind of experience? I know it definitely could be done with Android devices.

Comment: It can be related to http://www.atpeaz.com/index.php/2010/fixing-the-iphone-bluetooth-internet-tethering-with-os-x/.

Comment: Yes, this article excellent describes what's PAN interface is and actions to set up sharing. My question is it possible to set up a server in this PAN network internally without creating a server in the Internet? Is there any limitations from iOS side?

Comment: Without more extensive research, I would imagine it would definitely be possible but not very worthwhile since the device hosting the server would probably experience a strain on resources. This is also dependent on the role and actions taking place on the "server" side of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804650/ios-devices-as-web-server) about setting up such a server on an iOS device.

You can do a very quick test by installing a network diagnostics app - e.g. I found one called Console Server by SikYi Chan on the App Store.

In this app, I added a "server connection" on port `12345` and started the server. Tethering from my Mac, in System Preferences -> Network I found that my tethered IP address was `172.20.10.2`. I guessed the iPhone was therefore on `172.20.10.1`, and did this:

```
% telnet 172.20.10.1 12345        
Trying 172.20.10.1...
Connected to 172.20.10.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello
```

And in Server Console in the iOS app I got:

[image]