# Background mode for Bluetooth PAN accessory

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, background-process

I have an accessory which receives internet connection via iPhone Personal hotspot.

And I developed a service on the device from which I plan to pull updates every 1 minute. Or as an alternative it keeps consistent websocket connection.

I know that I can communicate to my device through Bluetooth PAN is possible however I would like to do it in background while the device is connected.
If someone is interested I asked a question before about this: [Is possible to communicate via Bluetooth PAN in iOS with tethered devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445656/is-possible-to-communicate-via-bluetooth-pan-in-ios-with-tethered-deviced)

What background mode could be used to keep consistent connection with my accessory through Bluetooth PAN network? Could modes "bluetooth-central" or "bluetooth-peripheral" or "external-accessory" be used without using CoreBluetooth or ExternalAccessory framework?