# How to transfer data from classic Bluetooth device to iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am writing an app for iOS that needs to receive data from a Bluetooth device (classic Bluetooth, not BLE).  I need a pretty fast data transfer, 1Mbit/s or faster if possible.  This already works using SPP in Android.

Apple only supports some Bluetooth profiles as listed here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387 I think these profiles are the only ones supported without being in the MFi program.  MFi is too difficult to deal with so I would really like to avoid it.  SPP is of course not available.

Of these profiles, PAN and maybe A2DP and HFP seem likely to be usable for bulk data transfer.  A2DP or HFP would be a hack as they are really not designed for non-audio data.  This seems to leave PAN.

**How can an iOS app transfer data from a classic Bluetooth device using PAN?**  I would like the app to connect and somehow establish a data connection.  This may be over IP (like tethering or reverse tethering using PAN) or non-IP.  I want something which behaves a lot like the SPP profile, in other words a bidirectional serial link between the two sides.

Note: The Bluetooth device on the other side of this can do anything that is needed (I am writing the device firmware at the same time using a bluetooth stack, probably the TI dual-mode stack).  Extra bounty if you can give me example of PAN tethering using any Bluetooth stack (TI, Synergy, dotstack etc).

See also: [Is possible to communicate via Bluetooth PAN in iOS with tethered devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445656/is-possible-to-communicate-via-bluetooth-pan-in-ios-with-tethered-deviced)

Comment: Short answer, you can't do it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Sigh, that's what I'm afraid of, but could you explain why PAN wouldn't work here?  If tethering works over PAN, presumably whatever is on the other side can get TCP/IP connectivity over the link, and it should be able to send data to the iPhone over TCP/IP.  What is the flaw with that idea?

Comment: You could try PAN.  That might work

Comment: @Paulw11Thanks!  Bounty for a working example... much bigger bounty for an example using an embedded Bluetooth stack :)

Comment: @EvanZimmerman: No, I did this as an Android only project for now.  I had posted a large bounty on this question and it expired with no answers. I'm still interested in an answer, let me know what you find...