# Can you use an iPhone as a web dev. server?

Tags: iphone

I am wondering if developing web services is possible using an iPhone as a web dev. server?

If so how?

Comment: I don't know why other people are minus it, I'd love to Dev whilst one the bus without any other devices,

Comment: A web *dev.* server? not sure what you mean?  For sure you can write your own implementation (serving static files), but using i.e. php, aspx, is another ball game.

Comment: Aren't you asking the same question as in this one?: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/6804650/2048108](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6804650/2048108)

Comment: also what do you mean by develop on the bus without other devices? I'd find it more than annoying to type code on the phone - even with a keyboard attached, you can't really grasp what you're typing, can you?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer). This is an open source HTTP server for Mac/iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It is cost effective and easy to run [Raspberry Pi as production webserver](http://raspberrywebserver.com/raspberrypicluster/raspberry-pi-cluster.html) simply because battery will not die, you can make cluster. iPhone as a web server is actually 7 years old idea, there is [apps](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/serversman/id302133974?mt=8), [News](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/the_iphone_becomes_a_web_server.php), video guides on YouTube.